# "-y" option in ffmpeg can't overwrite exist file rightly

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to overwrite the exists .wav file automatically

and I found a option from the [document of the ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options):

> -y (global)
>
> Overwrite output files without asking.

and I have a test:

```
ffmpeg -i 113.wav -ar 8000 -y 113.wav
```

but what I got is a .wav file with only 1 second duration, It's 2m30s duration before!
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSHfU.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvAfO.png)

If without the "-y" option, and type "y" after the command line reminder, all is Ok

```
File '113.wav' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
```

I'm really confused, and waiting for your response.

THX

Comment: ffmpeg does not do in-place editing! Output file must be different.

Comment: oh, I see. and If it has been mentioned in the document ? Or how you come to the conclusion? please, I just feel interesting about this.